# Azure data Factory - Find Inactive pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

As per [MS docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/), even inactive pipelines i.e. pipelines which are not running or do not have any trigger associated charge us. I am looking for a way to find out such inactive pipelines across all ADFs inside subscription.

I checked Get-AzDataFactoryV2 can list down all ADF's but it's not helping get pipelines without any trigger.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that doc where it says that you are charged for inactive pipelines. Anyway. You need to get all pipelines with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get then get all triggers with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/get. Triggers tell you which pipleine they are connected to so remove these from the list. That still doesn't tell you which ones are manually executed though

Comment: In addition to above, you can use ADF REST API [Query by Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory) to get the list of pipeline runs, and delete those pipelines that have not run once in the last 30 days. ADF pricing page mentions 'inactive' pipelines are those that did not run once in a month.

Comment: Azure DF pricing page says "A pipeline is considered inactive if it has no associated trigger or any runs within the month".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , thanks for sharing, pls scroll down to the bottom of page & its mentioned "An inactive pipeline is charged at $0.80 per month".

Comment: I stand corrected. In that case you just need to extract logs with the rest api with a suitable filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Export template` option.

[image]

Use ARM template as input to powershell and run github code given [here](https://github.com/mrpaulandrew/BlogSupportingContent/blob/master/Best%20Practices%20for%20Implementing%20Azure%20Data%20Factory%20-%20Auto%20Checker%20Script%20v0.1/ADF%20Checker%20Script%20v0.1.ps1)

You will get

1. Pipeline without any triggers attached. Directly or indirectly.
2. Pipeline(s) with an impossible AND/OR activity execution chain.

For more information follow this [blog](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2020/11/09/best-practices-for-implementing-azure-data-factory-auto-checker-script-v0-1/) by [mrpaulandrew](http://en.gravatar.com/mrpaulandrew)